# write "files" to read-only system and read them

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have Raspbian (raspberry pi) and I did this to make it read-only:

```
dphys-swapfile swapoff
dphys-swapfile uninstall
update-rc.d dphys-swapfile disable

aptitude install unionfs-fuse

nano /usr/local/bin/mount_unionfs:
[ -z "$1" ] && exit 1 || DIR=$1
ROOT_MOUNT=$(grep -v "^#" /etc/fstab | awk '$2=="/" {print substr($4,1,2)}')
if [ "$ROOT_MOUNT" != "ro" ]; then
/bin/mount --bind ${DIR}_org ${DIR}
else
/bin/mount -t tmpfs ramdisk ${DIR}_rw
/usr/bin/unionfs-fuse -o cow,allow_other,suid,dev,nonempty ${DIR}_rw=RW:${DIR}_org=RO ${DIR}
fi

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mount_unionfs


Update fstab to look like this:
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    ro                0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    ro,noatime        0       1
mount_unionfs   /etc            fuse    defaults          0       0
mount_unionfs   /var            fuse    defaults          0       0
none            /tmp            tmpfs   defaults          0       0

cp -al /etc /etc_org
mv /var /var_org
mkdir /etc_rw
mkdir /var /var_rw
reboot
```

Now, what I need to do is this: I have apache running and from time to time I need to store png files to temporary memory as normal files (I think in memory) and then show them in php script (for download). I know when I lose power these files are gone (this is ok). My problem is, that I don't know where should I store these files (path)? 
Maybe it is clear for someone right from fstab settings, but I don't understand fstab directives, so please tell me where to store it and how to access it then.

Comment: Check out [this answer from askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount)

Comment: Thanks @JNevill! I am just wondering when I mount some path to ram, if the access right are the same as dir on the hdd (?).

Comment: It will probably be whatever the perms of the directory to which you mount it since there won't be anything in there on mount (since it's ram).